# Using MutationObserver to wait for button to appear

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to create something that automatically clicks the required buttons on stackexchange type sites so that I can stop doing it myself. I am using a content script. I am trying to:

1. Find the button to customize cookies
2. click accept (they're usually all deselected with stackexchange sites)

Here is my code so far. I think it finds the right node, but clicks it too soon? I am not entirely sure since I'm new to js and whatnot.

```
function AcceptCustomization() {
    let myNode;

    let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return
    
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            // do things to your newly added nodes here
            let node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
    
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                node
                var a = node.getElementsByClassName("flex--item s-btn s-btn__primary save-preference-btn-handler onetrust-close-btn-handler js-consent-banner-hide js-consent-save")[0]
                if (a) {
                    myNode = a
                    console.log(myNode)
                    console.log(myNode.click())
                }
            }
    
        }
        })
    })

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true
    , subtree: true
    , attributes: false
    , characterData: false
    })
}

function CustomizeCookies() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("flex--item s-btn s-btn__filled js-cookie-settings")[0];
    if (a) {
        a.click();
        AcceptCustomization();
    }
    else {
        console.log(a);
    }
}

CustomizeCookies();
```

In the future, I want to create an extension that I can use to create a sort of database of websites with corresponding button clicks. For example, if I don't have the cookie customization for a website, I would click the extension and run a script that captures my button clicks and redoes them every future time I visit (if it is not the same session).

Thanks :)

Comment: There's no need for MutationObserver. Here's the entire content script: `document.querySelector('.js-accept-cookies')?.click()`

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, thanks for the reply! I'm looking to get something that doesn't accept any cookies other than functional ones. Am I right in assuming I'm going to need something different for most websites?